# How to update rails 3.0.3 to 3.1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

How do I update to Rails 3.1 ?

I am using windows xp with ruby console.

And is there a smart way to update a rails app from 3.0.3 to 3.1 or do I need to rewrite it all?

Comment: First I did type gem list in my ruby console. Second I typed gem uninstall rails and did choise to uninstall all my rails versions. Third: I did type: set HOMEPATH= and after that I could type "gem intall rails"

Comment: Protip: use *rvm* so you don't have to install and uninstall rails... especially if you work with more than one rails project, in which case you will eventually have them in different rails versions!

Comment: @ANeves RVM isn't available for windows unfortunately.

Comment: @SaucyK D'OH, thx for the correction. (Too bad.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question has a lot of useful information which might help you out: [Upgrading from Rails 3 to Rails 3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5968131/upgrading-from-rails-3-to-rails-3-1)

It doesn't answer specifically for Windows, but there's a lot of advice and insight that you'll find useful for the upgrade.

The only advice I can offer on top of reading the answers in the above question is to have a bit of patience and not expect it to work straight away. There's a lot of changes in the way 3.1 works so expect to spend some time fixing it up.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I created one vanilla 3.0 site, added it to Git, then created a vanilla 3.1 site and copied it over the 3.0 site, deleting existing files first.  A diff then showed me exactly what changed.

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly recommend [this](http://railscasts.com/episodes/225-upgrading-to-rails-3-part-1) and the following two railscasts in the series

Comment: -1: because links die, they are not a useful answer by themselves.